# SQLAlchemy ORM get rid of global metadata

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

A sample program:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Table, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Dog(Base):
    __tablename__ = "kennel"
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    def get_table(self):
        return Table(self.name, self.metadata, Column('bone', String))
```

Sample usage:

```
def f():
    spot = Dog("Spot")
    spot_stash = spot.get_table()

f()
f()
```

Exception:

> InvalidRequestError: Table 'Spot' is already defined for this MetaData
>   instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and
>   columns on an existing Table object.

I cannot call function `f()` twice in a row because metadata is global. I don't want to "extend_existing", just call a stand-alone function from a different place in the program. I do not see how to make `Base` non-global since a static class declaration depends on it. Is there a way around using a global variable of such epic proportions?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `get_table()` function? Can you explain. Any use case?

Comment: @Laurent LAPORTE ...so for each dog in the kennel I want to fetch each dog's table where he keeps bones and add a t-bone. Later on in the program I want to recreate dogs and fetch their respective tables again for another operation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. What do you mean by "fetch each dog's table", Are you speaking about records?

Comment: @Laurent LAPORTE each Dog is a complex product that has many tables associated with it, more like entire databases. They span millions of rows of data and have slightly different set of columns for each and every dog at our company.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to get the table associated with the `Dog` class but in fact are creating a *new* `Table` in your `get_table()` method. That's why it's complaining about a *Table* already existing in the current database.

Comment: I don't actually call Table.create(). It is already created and exists in the database, all I need is to access it.  I could "reflect" it back from the database but that would be slow, especially given that the program has access to table definition already.

Comment: @Muposat You are mistaking creating a table in SQL with creating a `Table` object. The act of creating a `Table` object will add that table to the specified `metadata`, causing this conflict.

Comment: @univerio I was aware of this. jknupp claimed that "it's complaining about a Table already existing in the current database," which is incorrect.